# Only hide duplicated fields in Crystal Reports

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, crystal-reports, duplicates

I have a table in a SQL Server 2008 R2 database like this:

```
Num     Total     Item     Item Value
--------------------------------------
1       5000      Cup      2000
1       5000      Brush    3000
2       2500      Kandy    2500
3       1000      Soap      750
3       1000      Rice      250
```

As you can see there is a duplication in the Num, Total columns, it must be like

```
Num     Total     Item     Item Value
----------------------------------------
1       5000      Cup      2000
                  Brush    3000

2       2500      Kandy    2500

3       1000      Soap      750
                  Rice      250
```

I've tried to use SQL `Group By` clause, but that didn't work. I also tried to suppress when duplicated in Crystal Reports, but it removes the entire row

So any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it,

Removing the duplicated fields by suppressing them when they are equal to it's previous record

Num Field ==> Suppress ==> Add this

```
{Num} = previous({Num})
```

Total Field ==> Suppress ==> Add this

```
{Total} = previous({Total})
```

Comment: insert a group for num and keep num and total in group header whereas item and item value in detail section and then in section expert the check on "Underlay following section"

Answer (score 0):

In the Group Expert inside of Crystal Reports, group your report on the *Num* and *Total* fields.